# updating time in database

Tags: php, mysql

```
$update_Premium = mysql_query("UPDATE `Users` SET PremiumTill='$PremiumTill' WHERE `UserName` = '{$view}'");

$date = gmdate("d-m-Y G:i");
$PremiumTill = ($date + (30 * 24 * 60 * 60));
```

I am wanting it so when the $update_premium kicks in it changes the date in database and adds the 30 days to the date.

Can it be done like this? or is there another way in which to do this?

Please help, thanks in advance.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 5):

There is a much easier way to do this:

```
UPDATE Users SET PremiumTill = DATE_ADD(PremiumTill, INTERVAL 30 DAY) WHERE ...
```

Comment: Wait a minute. You're using D-M-Y dates? That's backwards -- not only does it sort wrong, but it's not what MySQL uses (Y-M-D). You'll need to change that first, THEN you can start using `DATE_ADD`.